# Отправка данных методом POST без формы

Tags: php

Как отправить данные методом POST без формы и без js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну судя по метке PHP, а не HTML, то так

```
<?  
/*
Simple HTTP POST.
Простой пример, показывающий использования метода POST и cURL.
Прежде чем использовать данный код убедитесь, что на Вашем хостинге есть cURL.
©oded by BuH@LicH at sysman.ru 2007
thx to Miscђka
*/
$url = "http://www.sysman.ru/index.php?act=Login&CODE=01"; // URL на которы посылаем запрос
$login = ''; // логин 
$password = ''; // пассворд

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // Устанавливаем URL на который посылать запрос  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //  Результат будет содержать заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // Результат будет возвращём в переменную, а не выведен.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); // Таймаут после 4 секунд 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Устанавливаем метод POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "referer=&t=&f=&st=&UserName=$login&PassWord=$password&CookieDate=1"); // посылаемые значения
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

if (strpos($result,'302 F')!== FALSE) echo "<b>Good!</b>";
else echo "<b>Bad</b>";
?>
```

Пример слизан с какого-то сайта.

Comment: Никак. Бгггг, а про curl я и не вспомнил...

Comment: Нет ничего не возможного. )

Comment: попробуем попозже

Comment: Есть: безхаковая верстка под FF4 и IE6. =)

Comment: @ling, `<h2 align="center">Безхаковая верстка под FF4 и IE6<h2/>` В смысле, смотря что верстать) А еще флэш - не хак)

@Зоркий, эт зря, как минимум сокеты/курл.

Comment: @Sh4dow, большинство макетов, попадавшихся мне, под IE6 без хаков не верстались.  
Но вот в плане программирования, действительно, ничего невозможного нет.